# Scandit sdk for iOS and Storyboard (barcode reader)

Tags: ios, barcode, barcode-scanner, scandit

I downloaded their sdk for testing.

I read the samples codes (and documentation) provided with their sdk, and i have a question : Please could you tell me how to use the barcode reader in an iOS project with a storyboard ?

I have an iPad app with a tabbar with multiple tabs and navigationControllers defined in a storyboard.

I would like to add (via the storyboard) a uiviewcontroller which will contain a reader view (and have in the same tab the reader view, the navigationBar and the tabBar).

Can you help me ?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking to do is fairly easy to implement. Create a new class for your view controller, and then follow the directions on the website for how to [integrate the API](http://www.scandit.com/support/getting-started-with-scandit-sdk-for-ios/) into your app.On an iPhone this is really easy to do. I created a custom interface for an iPad version of my app that uses a popover controller, which took some doing to create the popover but once you have that adding in the custom class is just like anything else in Storyboard.